# Create a PL/SQL block to insert a new record into the Department table. Fetch the maximum department id from the Department table and add 10 to it;

Tags: oracle, plsql

Create a PL/SQL block to insert a new record into the Department table. Fetch the maximum department id from the Department table and add 10 to it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't see images, but - here's how I understood your homework:

Current table contents:

```
SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_ins_dept (par_dname in varchar2, par_loc in varchar2) is
  2    l_deptno number;
  3  begin
  4    select max(deptno)
  5      into l_deptno
  6      from dept;
  7
  8    insert into dept (deptno, dname, loc)
  9      values (nvl(l_deptno, 0) + 10, par_dname, par_loc);
 10  end;
 11  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> exec p_ins_dept ('Test', 'Zagreb');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME                LOC
---------- -------------------- --------------------
        50 Test                 Zagreb                    --> here it is
        10 ACCOUNTING           NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH             DALLAS
        30 SALES                CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS           BOSTON

SQL>
```

---

Note that such an approach is likely to fail in a multi-user environment where

- two (or more) users simultaneously call the procedure,
- fetch `MAX` department number value
- add `10` to it
- insert a row
- which fails for the 2nd (and other) user because primary key is violated because of the 1st user - who successfully inserted the row

But OK; for a simple homework question, I guess you don't care much about such things.